# Is it possible to store style properties in a js array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, styles

I created a bunch of style properties and I'd like to use a for loop to add them to a div element. I can't figure out what is wrong with my syntax :

```
function createShot(){

var shot = new shotConstructor(spaceship.x,(765-(spaceship.y+15)),15,15,"#000000","","","","","","");
var createDiv = document.createElement("div");
var AddId = createDiv.setAttribute("id","shot");
var element = document.getElementById("dv_grid");
var append = element.appendChild(createDiv);
var shotStyle=document.getElementById('shot').style;
var style=[width=shot.w+"px",height=shot.h+"px",left=shot.x+"px",top=shot.y+"px",backgroundColor="#000000",position="absolute"];

for(i=0;i<6;i++){
    shotStyle+style[i];

}
```

Comment: Missing a `}` that closes the for-loop for starters.

Comment: `shotStyle+style[i];` does nothing

Comment: What shall I do then?

Answer (score 0):

```
[width=shot.w+"px"]
 ^^^^^
```

That is a global variable.

```
[width=shot.w+"px"]
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That is a value you assign to the global variable.

The value is then *also* placed in the array.

This gives you an array of style property values which are not associated with any property name.

---

```
shotStyle+style[i];
```

This converts the CSSStyleDeclaration to a string, appends the style property value (no property name remember!) to that string and then discards the result (since you don't assign it anywhere).

---

You need to store the property names with the values. Since order doesn't matter, you should do that by using an object instead of an array.

```
var style = {
    width: shot.w + "px",
    height: shot.h + "px",
    left: shot.x + "px",
    top: shot.y + "px",
    backgroundColor: "#000000",
    position: "absolute"
};
```

You then need appropriate syntax to loop over the object and use both the name and value of each property.

```
for (var prop in style) {
    shotStyle[prop] = style[prop];
}
```